# I am getting compile error expected identified function error

Tags: excel, vba

I am inserting this code in vba Excel and after i run debug compile it gives me Compile error
expected identifier
Function

```
End `Option Explicit

Function Validate() As Boolean

Dim frm As Worksheet

Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")

Validate = True

With frm

    .Range("I6").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I8").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I10").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I12").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I14").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I16").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I18").Interior.Color = xlNone
    .Range("I20").Interior.Color = xlNone
    
End With

'Validating Trainee ID
If Trim(frm.Range("I6").Value) = "" Then
MsgBox "Trainee Id is blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Trainee ID"
frm.Range("I6").Select
frm.Range("I6").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If

'Validating Trainee Name
If Trim(frm.Range("I8").Value) = "" Then
MsgBox "Trainee Name is blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Trainee Name"
frm.Range("I8").Select
frm.Range("I8").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If

'Validating Gender
If Trim(frm.Range("I10").Value) <> "Female" And Trim(frm.Range("I10").Value) <> "Male" = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select valid Gender from Drop-dpwn.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Gender"
frm.Range("I10").Select
frm.Range("I10").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If

'Validating Department
If Trim(frm.Range("I12").Value) = "" Then
MsgBox "Department is blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Department"
frm.Range("I12").Select
frm.Range("I12").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If

'Validating Country
If Trim(frm.Range("I14").Value) = "" Then
MsgBox "Country is blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Country"
frm.Range("I14").Select
frm.Range("I14").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If

'Validating Training
If Trim(frm.Range("I16").Value) = "" Then
MsgBox "Training is blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Training"
frm.Range("I16").Select
frm.Range("I16").Interior.Color = vbRed
Validate = False
Exit Function
End If
```

I am inserting this code in vba Excel and after i run debug compile it gives me Compile error
expected identifier

```
Function    
    'Validating Format
    If Trim(frm.Range("I18").Value) <> "Face to Face" And Trim(frm.Range("I18").Value) <> "Online" = "" 
    Then
    MsgBox "Please select valid Format from Drop-dpwn.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Format"
    frm.Range("I18").Select
    frm.Range("I18").Interior.Color = vbRed
    Validate = False
    Exit Function
    End If

    'Validating Year Taken
    If Trim(frm.Range("I20").Value) = "" Or Not IsNumeric(Trim(frm.Range("I20").Value)) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter year of taking the course.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Year Taken"
    frm.Range("I20").Select
    frm.Range("I20").Interior.Color = vbRed
    Validate = False
    Exit Function
    End If`
```

Function

I am inserting this code in vba Excel and after i run debug compile it gives me Compile error
expected identifier
Function

Comment: Please post the code directly from the VBE as you seem to have stray lines at the top and bottom and it's not clear whether this is genuine or just a copying error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

```vb
End `Option Explicit
```

`Option Explicit` should be the first thing on the first line; that `End`` looks like a copy-paste artifact.

This however, could very well be the cause of the compile error you're describing:

```vb
Function    
    'Validating Format
```

The `Function` keyword is part of a grammatical syntax rule that the language follows/implements, to understand the code you're writing.

The rules around `Function` (and `Sub`, and `Property`) keyword make the VBA parser/compiler expect an *identifier name* immediately following a space after the `FUNCTION` token:

```
Function NameOfTheFunction
```

If you type this into the VBE, you'll get a legal parameterless function definition that looks like this:

```
Function NameOfTheFunction()
|
End Function
```

The `()` parentheses delimit the function's *parameter list*, where you may define any [reasonable] number of parameters for your function:

- `ByVal NameOfTheParameter` to pass the parameter *by value*;
- `ByRef NameOfTheParameter`, or just `NameOfTheParameter`, to pass the parameter *by reference*;
- Add an `As` clause to each parameter, to specify a parameter type.

---

It looks like you copied a chunk of code starting at the `Function` of `Exit Function` of a previous block, and then pasted a stray `Function` keyword in the middle of your code.

It looks like the problem could be generalized, which would prevent such mistakes from occurring in the future by virtue of making the code simpler to extend.

Presumably some cells have a data validation dropdown. If such cells contain an invalid value, the worksheet already knows, so we can defer dropdown validation to Excel. This also covers validating whether a value is a number (or a date) between X and Y, and with the "ignore blank" option cleared it also covers required values when crafted as a "text length" rule that requires a content length greater than 0.

So what we really need is a function that tells us whether a given cell has validation errors, and let Excel's native data validation do the rest:

```vb
Private Function HasErrors(ByVal TargetCell As Range) As Boolean
    HasErrors = Not Application.Intersect(TargetCell, TargetCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Then we can have a `ValidateField` procedure that validates a single field:

```vb
Private Function ValidateField(ByVal TargetCell As Range, Optional ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal Title As String = "Validation Failed")
    'data validation can hold the error message, no need to hard-code this data:
    If Message = vbNullString Then Message = TargetCell.Validation.ErrorMessage
    If HasErrors(TargetCell) Then
        ValidateField = False
        TargetCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        TargetCell.Select
        MsgBox Message, vbOkOnly + vbInformation, Title
    Else
        ValidateField = True
        TargetCell.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
End Function
```

And now the `Validate` macro can melt into this (assuming the validation messages are moved to data validation):

```vb
Public Function Validate() As Boolean ' consider making this a Sub procedure
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form") 'consider using the sheet's codename instead
        'consider naming these ranges:
        If Not ValidateField(.Range("I6")) Then Exit Function
        If Not ValidateField(.Range("I8")) Then Exit Function
        If Not ValidateField(.Range("I10")) Then Exit Function
        '...
        'named ranges would enhance readability:
        If Not ValidateField(.Range("Country")) Then Exit Function
        If Not ValidateField(.Range("YearTaken")) Then Exit Function
    End With
    Validate = True
End Function
```

Note that with extensive data validation defined on all fields, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form").CircleInvalid` would have Excel draw a red validation circle around all invalid fields in the form.